# How to find number of solutions using the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I know these are probably well-known results, but I want to find how many roots a function has using its derrivatives.
Consider a two times differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. If $f''(x) =0$ has only one root, does this tell me anything about how many roots $f(x) =0$ has? Can this be generalised?

Comment: Knowing that $f''$ has only one root does not tell you very much about $f$ itself.  For example, if $f''$ is a linear function (therefore possessing only one root), then $f$ is cubic.  A cubic function can have either one or three real roots.  Things can get more interesting if we don't require our functions to be algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's imagine that the roots of $f$ are all distinct.

Suppose the function had $4$ distinct roots, $a<b<c<d$.  Then we know that $f'(x)$ has a root in $(a,b)$, another in $(b,c)$, and a third in $(c,d)$.  Between any two roots of $f'$ there is a root of $f''$.  Thus, in this situation there would be at least $2$ roots of $f''$.  Thus $f(x)$ can have at most $3$ roots.  The cubic $f(x)=x^3-x$ has three distinct roots and $f''(x)=6x$ has only a single root, so this bound is sharp.